# Scala actor apparently not receiving messages

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Could you please explain why the following code is not working as expected.

The actor is not printing the message

Thanks.

```
class Base {
  def f() = { "This is Base" }
}

class Sub extends Base {
  override def f() = { "This is Sub" }
}

case class myCase(x: Base)

import scala.actors._

object myActor extends Actor {

  def act()
  {
    loop {
      react {
        case myCase(x) => x.f()
        case msg => "unknown"
      }
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    this ! myCase(new Base)
    this ! myCase(new Sub)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answering the question

The problem has nothing whatsoever to do with inheritance or case classes (I have re-titled the question to reflect this). The code does not print anything for two reasons:

1. Because *your code does not actually make any calls to `println`*! Replace:

   ```
   case myCase(x) => x.f()
   ```

   with

   ```
   case myCase(x) => println( x.f() )
   ```
2. Because *you do not start your actor*. I think your program would make more sense if the actor were an inner class:

   ```
   object myActor extends App {

     class MyActor extends Actor {
       def act() {
         loop {
           react {
             ...             // <-- You need to print stuff
           }
         }
       }
     }

     val a = new MyActor
     a.start()             // <-- You need to start it
     a ! myCase(new Base)
     a ! myCase(new Sub)
   }
   ```

---

### Advice: case classes and inheritance

I would, however, offer the advice that using inheritance in the presence of case classes is **a bad idea**. I usually use the approach of declaring common behaviour/state in a trait:

```
sealed trait Base {
  def f(): Unit
}

case class Sub() extends Base
```

Why is it a bad idea? Well, one of the contracts that case-classes give you is a rigid definition of *equivalence* (that is, an `equals` and `hashCode` implementation). In the presence of inheritance, this could well be *misleading*. That is, your code will probably not do what you expect. Consider the following;

```
scala> abstract class Base { val x: Int }
defined class Base

scala> case class Sub(s: String) extends Base { val x = util.Random.nextInt(100) }
defined class Sub
```

Now if I create 2 instances...

```
scala> Sub("Hey")
res2: Sub = Sub(Hey)

scala> Sub("Hey")
res3: Sub = Sub(Hey)
```

They are equivalent

```
scala> res2 == res3
res4: Boolean = true
```

But they do not have the same state

```
scala> res2.x
res5: Int = 28

scala> res3.x
res7: Int = 15
```

Note, I am not saying this is a bug. I'm just saying it's an area where you might find that you *introduce* a bug in your code because you have made the assumption that any state of the case class is included in its equivalence.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am new to Scala and the concept of Trait is still not clear to me.

Comment: If you are coming from a Java background, a `trait` is just an `interface` which can contain implementation. This has a profound impact on the language because it means that API designers can design a very *rich* library without incurring a heavy penalty to *implementors*. That is, any implementor of `java.util.Collection` must implement 13 methods - an implementor of `Traversable` must implement only one (for which they then get > 90 other methods for free). I rarely (never, in fact) use abstract classes.

Comment: If a trait is an interface which can contain implementation which can also be extended, then what makes it different from the abstract class?

Comment: You can inherit from **multiple traits**, but you can only extend one superclass